# Universal Func<> type in c#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, lisp

I'm writing a small Lisp interpreter in C#, and it's basically working already. Currently I'm using an interface to represent functions:

```
public interface LispFunction
{
    object Apply(ArrayList parameters);
}
```

The interface is implemented by multiple classes for internal (standard) functions, lambdas, macro expansion, calling methods in .net objects via reflection and so on. Please note that speed is NOT an issue here, just the joy of getting the interpreter to, and use it at, work.

Now I'd like my little Lisp to accept arbitrary C# lambdas to be used within the interpreter, like this:

```
Lisp foo = new Lisp();
foo.GlobalEnvironment.AddFunction("test", (bool a, int b) => a ? b : "whoops");
foo.Eval(foo.Read("(test #t 5)")); // Should evaluate to (object) 5
```

First thing that came to my mind was using `Func<...>`, but I'd have to use lots of overloaded methods for `Func<a>`, `Func<a, b>`, `Func<a, b, c>` and so on.

Is there a possibility in C# to accept arbitrary lambdas to be called via reflection later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a possibility in C# to accept arbitrary lambdas to be called via reflection later?

Well you can write a method to take an arbitrary *delegate*:

```
public void AddFunction(string name, Delegate function)
```

However, the conversion from a lambda expression has to be as a specific delegate, so you'd need:

```
Func<bool, string, string> function = (a, b) => a ? b : "whoops"
foo.GlobalEnvironment.AddFunction("test", function);
```

Or cast within the call:

```
foo.GlobalEnvironment.AddFunction("test",
    (Func<bool, string, string>)((a, b) => a ? b : "whoops"));
```

You could put all the overloading in *one* place, keeping `AddFunction` entirely general, but having a static class like this (a bit like `Tuple`):

```
public static class Func
{
    public Func<TResult> Create(Func<TResult> function) { return function; }

    public Func<T1, TResult> Create(Func<T1, TResult> function)
    {
        return function;
    }

    public Func<T1, T2, TResult> Create(Func<T1, T2, TResult> function)
    {
        return function;
    }

    // etc
}
```

This class basically *just* exists for convenience. You'd then call:

```
foo.GlobalEnvironment.AddFunction("test",
    Func.Create((bool a, string b) => a ? b : "whoops"));
```

Comment: ...That's it, thanks! I'll use the cast-within-call variant for now, and switch to the convenience approach later, when it comes to polishing. The full call looks like this ATM: `lisp.GlobalEnvironment.Define(Symbol.GetSymbol("test"), (Func<int, bool, object>)((a, b) => b ? (object)a : (object)"Whoops"));`

Comment: ...just noticed your answer came FOUR minutes after my question. Was going to ask "Are you Jon Skeet?!". Then I noticed. Mind == blown.

Comment: OK, now it looks like I wanted it to :) `lisp.GlobalEnvironment.AddFunction("test", (int a, bool b) => b ? a : (object)"Whoops");`